# WHERE clause in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

This is mysql statement

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `error_report` AS e
                 INNER JOIN `pages` AS p ON e.page_id=p.page_id
                WHERE `task_id` ='".$this->task_id."' AND 
                    ((google_host_fail=1
                    OR robots_noindex_nofollow=1
                    OR xrobots_noindex_nofollow=1
                    OR google_cache_fail=1
                    OR forbidden_word=1)
                    OR (google_title_fail=1 AND h1_fail=1 AND h2_fail=1 AND h3_fail=1))";
```

I want here, to return results on condition that there is task id.. and or any of the two satements enclosed in brackets
The problem is in the last where statement, I want a condition that if all those fields.

I have got another sql problem with a similar statement.

```
     public function check_success()
  {
      $query="SELECT e.* FROM `error_report` AS e
           INNER JOIN `pages` AS p ON e.page_id=p.page_id
            WHERE `task_id` ='".$this->task_id."' 
                AND ((google_title_fail=0) OR (google_title_fail=1 AND h1_fail=0))";
      $result=$this->db->query($query)->result_array();
      if(count($result)>0)
      {
          return 1;
      }
     return 0;
  }
```

I want to achieve the same above.. But I dont see that my statements work

How can I enclose the where statements with brackets so that they will work in both functions..

```
   public function findFinalResult()
  {
      if($this->check_fail())
      {
          return "Failure";
      }
     else if($this->check_success())
     {
         return "Success";
     }
     return "Warning";

  }
```

Final results gives fail each time..? why ?!?

Comment: It'd probably help to see the source of the `check_fail()` function.

Comment: is task_id really a string? if you debug some rendered sql statements, and execute them directly in a sql browser (like phpmyadmin), do you get results there?

Comment: check fail , is the first statmenet

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM error_report AS e INNER JOIN pages AS p ON e.page_id=p.page_id WHERE task_id ='151' AND (OR google_host_fail=1 OR robots_noindex_nofollow=1 OR xrobots_noindex_nofollow=1 OR google_cache_fail=1 OR forbidden_word=1) OR (google_title_fail=1 AND h1_fail=1 AND h2_fail=1 AND h3_fail=1)
```

The error occurs due the unecessary OR statement at the beginning of the brackets.

```
...AND (OR google_host_fail=1 OR robots_noindex_nofollow=1
OR xrobots_noindex_nofollow=1 OR google_cache_fail=1 OR forbidden_word=1)...
```

Comment: I fixed it..there is no error...But why does it return results..see update